# See if two images intersect while ignoring empty space

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiimageview, uiimage

Currently I am using the `CGRectIntersectsRect` method between my two `UIImageViews` but is is possible to ignore the empty space of the .png's. For example if you're trying to see if two circles intersect rather then if the square frames that they're in are touching?

Comment: I think it not possible to do. Had the same problem, solved it by using some shape which represents best your image object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to detect when the non-transparent part of an UIImage is in contact with another non-transparent part of an UIImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22771662/how-to-detect-when-the-non-transparent-part-of-an-uiimage-is-in-contact-with-ano)